# cURL POST --data-binary vs --form

Tags: post, curl

I have a simple question regarding to the usage of cURL.  Didn't find much during my Google search or Man page to get a clear answer.

In [here](https://superuser.com/questions/361504/how-to-send-post-with-body-data-headers-andhttp-params-over-the-curl-command) talks about using either `--data` vs `--form` on sending file/attachment. I'm curious to know what are the main difference and under what scenarios you would pick `--data-binary` VS `--form` ?

The POST "body" can be sent via either `--data (for application/x-www-form-urlencoded)` or `--form (for multipart/form-data)`:

```
-F "foo=bar"                  # 'foo' value is 'bar'
-F "foo=<foovalue.txt"        # the specified file is sent as plain text input
-F "foo=@foovalue.txt"        # the specified file is sent as an attachment

-d "foo=bar"
-d "foo=<foovalue.txt"
-d "foo=@foovalue.txt"
-d "@entirebody.txt"          # the specified file is used as the POST body

--data-binary "@binarybody.jpg"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is explained in the [HTML 4.01 Specification section on Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4):

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the default content type.
>
> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

Comment: Would it fail if the content-type is specified as "multipart/form-data", but they send it as --data-binary, when using curl?

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly the main difference, type of data that's being sent to the server (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` vs `multipart/form-data`)

Comment: Thanks! 

What are the scenarios you will use either type of data?
so `form-urlencoded` is for embedded the data into the request, but multipart is different?